# unable to remove ASP net MVC version from response headers in TFS 2018

Tags: iis, tfs

I need to remove this information from API response headers.

"x-aspnetmvc-version": "4.0",

I'm using Windows Server 2016 IIS 10 
Team Foundation Server 2018 Release 2

I’ve read that this can be removed in the global.asax file using the following block of code

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

I’m using Team Foundation Server 2018 and my global.asax file looks like this

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.TeamFoundationApplication" %>
```

Which is an application directive.

If I add,

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

Then restart IIS the TFS web application won’t load.

Any ideas?  is my syntax wrong?  I assume this is a code declaration box and I'm missing some information

Comment: **Why** do you need to do this? You should absolutely not be messing with the app tier.

Comment: I'd rather not mess with it but our Information Security department is wanting us to remove any version information from the response header.  Attackers can target vulnerabilities based on that particular version.   If this isnt possible well have to submit an exception which is kind of a pain.

Comment: Submit the exception. You're at high risk of breaking your TFS installation. You're not meant to mess around with the code.